Monthly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Lightning Development Kit‽
Lightning Development Kit (LDK) is a library to integrate Lightning into existing Bitcoin wallet projects written in Rust. Our site so far has only a single question about LDK. That feels like an oversight!
Maybe our topic week is a prompt for you to learn more about its functionality, have a look at their code base, or try to play around with LDK. However you engage with it, please be sure to use lightning-development-kit (or the synonym ldk) when you ask all questions that come up while exploring.
Are you already working on integrating LDK into something? Did you resolve some blockers already? Add a question and answer it yourself to help the next developer.
Please also check out other topics that get started to add additional answers where they are missing, improve existing posts where they can be improved, and vote on what's there.
This weekly topic challenge runs from 2023-01-04 – 2023-01-10. Happy posting!

Unfortunately, no new posts were added to lightning-development-kit topics this week.
